# Math.StackExchange chat Room

Tags: discussion, chat

I created a chat room for us [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80/math-stackexchange). There are plans for each Stack Exchange site to eventually have its own chat site, but a single chat room should be fine for now.

Comment: There's an IRC channel on Freenode (#mathexchange), but no-one seems to have caught on yet.

Comment: +1 for IRC.  IRC can do better anything that any newer chat can do (aside from audio and video conferencing).  If the SE chat team is reading this, please allow access to the official webchat through IRC (perhaps by making the backend an IRC server).  IRC, unlike other flavours of "chat", is very open to community-building.  Once you have a channel populated by five to six regulars (and a few idlers, perhaps), it's very easy for the community (i.e. the original five or six seed members) to snowball into something much bigger.

Comment: It says you need 20 reputation on meta.SO to talk, which is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 6):

For info, [chat.stackexchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is now open; please feel free to use this as desired. There should be a "chat" link at the top of every page on the Q&A site.